# Hyphenated urls for controller name in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I'm trying to map my urls that look like `/action-figure/` to the `ActionFigureController`. i.e., have my url be hyphen separated for the controllers.

Something like [this answer exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176525), but for WebApi instead of MVC routing.

How do I configure my urls in WebApi please?

Almost all google search directs me to MVC routing configurations and I am not able to find the equivalent of it for:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

as `MvcRouteHandler` doesn't apply to this and I am not sure where to even pass in the custom route config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it might not be possible to set multiple routes as in ASP.NET MVC, try to go for [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) to make use of easy to use annotations for specifying routes.

To enable attribute routing you need to set this in your `Register`method:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

That gives you the convenience of setting the routes for each method:

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
```

Also, [`RoutePrefix`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes) allows to avoid repetitively providing the whole path:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/books")]
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/books
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Book> Get() { ... }

    // GET api/books/5
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public Book Get(int id) { ... }

    // POST api/books
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Book book) { ... }
}
```

**EDIT** Coming back to your comment:

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31469979/155668) and the way the `DefaultHttpControllerSelector` is derived from and filled with some logic:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Dispatcher;

public class ApiControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    public ApiControllerSelector (HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration) { }

    public override string GetControllerName(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        // add logic to remove hyphen from controller name lookup of the controller
        return base.GetControllerName(request).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

To make this work you then need to specify the custom `ApiControllerSelector` in the config like this:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector),
            new ApiControllerSelector(config));
```

Comment: hi, thanks, is there no way to globally configure, with a bit of logic, to turn camel case controllers into hyphen seperated urls?

Comment: See updated answer, there's a way at least to intercept the request and alter the controller parameter there.